# How to transfer file to a vm in vcloud director and execute it?

Tags: c#, .net, vmware, powercli, vcloud-director-rest-api

I am using vcloud director .net sdk 5.5 to automate the vcloud director operations.

I want to transfer a file from my physical machine to the vcloud vm and execute it on the vm.
In vsphere .net sdk, `InitiateFileTransferToGuest` method of `GuestFileManager` and `StartProgramInGuest` method of `GuestProcessManager` can be used to perform these actions.

Is there any equivalent api method in vcloud sdk to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked at the vcloud sdk [documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/vcd_pubs.html) ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Yup..i started with the developer's guide. I dont see any info regarding the file management in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find such a method because it utilizes the VMware Tools in the guest and the "backdoor" between the VM and hypervisor to transfer the file, which makes it harder to scale and implement in a "cloudy" way. The answer from VMware would likely be to transfer the file to your guest via other user-level means (SCP, FTP, HTTP, etc.) that don't require cooperation from the hypervisor.

If you need this soon after the system boots you could utilize the customization script [[1](http://pubs.vmware.com/vcd-55/topic/com.vmware.vcloud.users.doc_55/GUID-724EB7B5-5C97-4A2F-897F-B27F1D4226C7.html?resultof=%22%73%63%72%69%70%74%22%20), [2](http://pubs.vmware.com/vcd-55/topic/com.vmware.vcloud.api.doc_55/GUID-1BA3B7C5-B46C-48F7-8704-945BC47A940D.html)] option to download the file, assuming it's posted in a network-accessible location.

Comment: does customization script runs every time the system reboots? it is mentioned it will run only during initial customization. Is it possible to run a script when the vm is powered on ?

Comment: No, it only runs when customization is triggered – usually when the VM is provisioned, but IIRC there is an option to force re-customization later.

If you want it to run on every start-up your best bet is to create your own shell script and install it on the machine as an init script or in rc.local so it happens on start (adding it to root's crontab with `@reboot` as the time can also work)